# Replace N spaces at the beginning of a line with N characters

Tags: regex, ruby, pcre

I am looking for a regex substitution to transform N  white spaces at the beginning of a line to N `&nbsp;`. So this text:

```
list:
  - first
```

should become:

```
list:
&nbsp;&nbsp;- first
```

I have tried:

```
str = "list:\n  - first"
str.gsub(/(?<=^) */, "&nbsp;")
```

which returns:

```
list:
&nbsp;- first
```

which is missing one `&nbsp;`. How to improve the substitution to get the desired output?

Comment: The title is not clear because N spaces aren't being replaced by N characters. (In your example each space is replaced with six characters.) Perhaps, "Replace each space at the beginning of a line with a given string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gsub` with a callback function:

```rb
str = "list:\n  - first"
output = str.gsub(/(?<=^|\n)[ ]+/) {|m| m.gsub(" ", "&nbsp;") }
```

This prints:

```
list:
&nbsp;&nbsp;- first
```

The pattern `(?<=^|\n)[ ]+` captures one or more spaces at the start of a line.  This match then gets passed to the callback, which replaces each space, one at a time, with `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of the [`\G` anchor](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) and `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

To match all leading single  spaces:

```
(?:\R\K|\G)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\R\K` Match a newline and clear the match buffer
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)`  Close non capture group and match a space

See a [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/5r96OTvcIgfdxr) and a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/O3aEUz).

---

To match only the single leading spaces in the example string:

```
(?:^.*:\R|\G)\K
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^.*:\R` Match a line that ends with `:` and match a newline
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, or at the start of the string
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\K`  Forget what is matched so far and match a space

See a [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/OuJ6553Sy4BOQp) and a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/Y8SJ6P).

Example

```
re = /(?:^.*:\R|\G)\K /
str = 'list:
  - first'
result = str.gsub(re, '&nbsp;')

puts result
```

Output

```
list:
&nbsp;&nbsp;- first
```

Comment: For OP: Change to `/(?:^list:\R|\G)\K /` if you have other lines starting with spaces you don't want replaced.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of `\G` and i don't fully grasp what it does but i will look more into it.

Comment: Ruby docs give the example `"    a b c".gsub(/\G /, '_')  #=> "____a b c"` but it is not very clear to me what `\G` does.

Comment: @builder-7000 There is more information on this page https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G and on this page https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html about the `\G` anchor.

Answer (score 2):

I would write

```
"list:\n  - first".gsub(/^ +/) { |s| '&nbsp;' * s.size }
  #=> "list:\n&nbsp;&nbsp;- first"
```

See [String#*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-2A)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short `/(?:\G|^) /` regex with a plain text `&nbsp;` replacement pattern:

```rb
result = text.gsub(/(?:\G|^) /, '&nbsp;')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YVvsEc/2). *Details*:

- `(?:\G|^)` - start of a line or string or the end of the previous match
- - a space.

See a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/b57ztC):

```rb
str = "list:\n  - first"
result = str.gsub(/(?:\G|^) /, '&nbsp;')
puts result
# => 
#  list:
#  &nbsp;&nbsp;- first
```

If you need to match any whitespace, replace   with a `\s` pattern. Or use `\h` if you need to only match horizontal whitespace.